# Set-PSReadLineKeyHandler get registered but cant be triggered

Tags: powershell

`Set-PSReadLineKeyHandler` not working. If I for example define:

```
Set-PSReadLineKeyHandler -Chord shift+B -ScriptBlock {
"Line 1"
"Line 2"
"Line 3"
}
```

And then run `Get-PSReadLineKeyHandler` just to see the user define actions:

```
Key Function Description  
--- -------- -----------  
Ctrl+j CustomAction User defined action  
Ctrl+B CustomAction User defined action  
B CustomAction User defined action
```

When it comes time to trigger the hotkeys nothing happens. None of the user defined hotkeys for actions trigger. No errors, just nothing.

---

**PSVersion 7.3.0-preview.7**

**PSReadLine 2.2.6**

**Windows Terminal Preview 1.15.2003.0**

Thanks for helping me.

Comment: Is your goal to output something to the console? if that is the case you should use `[Microsoft.PowerShell.PSConsoleReadLine]::Insert("Line 1")`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As Otter's comment says, to write text or move the cursor around you need to call methods to make PSReadLine do those things. See the [`Set-PSReadLineKeyHandler`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/psreadline/set-psreadlinekeyhandler?view=powershell-7.2#example-2-bind-a-key-to-a-script-block) documentation, e.g. example 2:

> This example shows how a single key can be used to run a command. The command binds the key Ctrl+B to a script block that clears the line, inserts the word "build", and then accepts the line.

```
Set-PSReadLineKeyHandler -Chord Ctrl+B -ScriptBlock {
    [Microsoft.PowerShell.PSConsoleReadLine]::RevertLine()
    [Microsoft.PowerShell.PSConsoleReadLine]::Insert('build')
    [Microsoft.PowerShell.PSConsoleReadLine]::AcceptLine()
}
```

At a PowerShell prompt you can start typing `[Microsoft.PowerShell.PSConsoleReadLine]::` and then press Ctrl+Space to get an autocomplete view of available methods; they are [documented here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.powershell.psconsolereadline?view=powershellsdk-1.1.0).

Comment: Awesome. Thank you so much for this example and the page you pointed me to. its working just fine now.